# perl in place edit replace multiple values same time

Tags: perl

All I am trying to do search and replace on a file.  The below code does not work.
What am I doing wrong?  Please help

```
  $file = "/tmp/file";
  my $date = qx/date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'/;
  @accounts = qw($account1 $account2 $account3 $account4);    

   @ARGV = ( $file ) ;
    $^I = ".$date" ;
     while (my $line=<>){
       for my $account (@accounts) {
        if ($line =~ /^$account/) {
     ..<search and replace>..
    print $line;
   }else{
      print $line ;
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write. It is only polite when you are asking for help with your code, as you haven't even taken the most minimal steps to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue I have is with loops. It is not working properly

Comment: Does the solution from `@choroba` not help you at all?

Answer (score 3):

`qw()` quotes words, it doesn't interpolate variables.

```
@accounts = qw($account1 $account2 $account3 $account4);
```

is equivalent to

```
@accounts = ('$account1', '$account2', '$account3', '$account4');
```

Note the single quotes!

Instead, use

```
@accounts = ($account1, $account2, $account3, $account4);
```

BTW, instead of calling shell to call `date`, you can use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece):

```
use Time::Piece;
my $lt   = localtime;
my $date = join '-', $lt->ymd(q()), $lt->hms(q());
```

Comment: My issue is not with array declaration or time. The loops are not working properly. If you can suggest an alternate way, it will be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is no input and what exactly you want in the output is not mentioned. How can we suggest a better solution. Please be clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that the line

```
$line =~ /^$account/
```

may not be doing what you expect.

try

```
$line =~ /^\Q$account\E/
```

This escapes any special characters ( special within a regex, for example brackets ) within the regexp and usually does what you want with a variable inside a regex.